# Can't implement adMob AdListener Class

Tags: android, admob

Im getting this error:

```
- The type AdListener cannot be a superinterface of AdManager; a superinterface must be an 
         interface
```

When im trying to implement ADMOB AdListener on my app:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;

public class AdManager implements AdListener{
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

According to the new SDK (Google Play Services)

You no longer implement AdListener from your Activity or class..

You can use it as an inner class:

`adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onAdLoaded() {}
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {}
  // Only implement methods you need.
});`

(Taken from: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration)

Answer (score 4):

[`AdListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html) is a class, not an interface so your class needs to inherit from it, not implement it. Use `extends` keyword, not `implements`.

```
public class AdManager extends AdListener{
}
```

Comment: if i extends that class, im not implementing it, and my objective is to implement it.... its the way admob works, you should implement adlistener

Comment: You cannot implement a class. You have to extend it and override methods you need, e.g. `onAdLoaded()`.

Comment: Google implemented it. See http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html#ImplementListeners

Comment: @VipulPurohit The link you posted is from the older Google AdMob SDK. The new Google Play Services offers the AdListener as a class which is different to the old Google AdMob SDK. old: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US#android new: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US#play

Comment: @BrunoBieri both the links you have posted are expired (Page not found). please update to the latest if possible. Thank you!!

Comment: @aB9 At google developers you can find a starting guide how to work with the Google AdMob SDK https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start and you also find the API Referenz as Szymon already linked: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary